# Memory not available but no process is using it

Tags: linux, centos7, memory, top

We are using a centos 7 server. The `free -m` command has the following output.

```
[root@211 ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          31841       31173         389           0         278         178
Swap:        382975          45      382930
```

It shows that most of the memory is being used. It's not used for caching the filesystem but by some kernel/user processes. We don't have any processes running on this system though. The output of `ps aux --sort=-%mem | head` is as follows

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       603  0.0  0.0 109300 14524 ?        Ss   Apr25   0:12 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root      1249  0.0  0.0 658752  6156 ?        Ssl  Apr25  36:56 /usr/bin/python2 -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
root         1  0.0  0.0 194160  4640 ?        Ss   Apr25   0:13 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
root     58818  0.0  0.0 155636  4008 pts/0    R+   12:26   0:00 ps aux --sort=-%mem
root     56093  0.0  0.0 117168  3080 pts/0    Ss   10:01   0:00 -bash
root      1252  0.0  0.0 728324  2404 ?        Ssl  Apr25   0:25 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root       867  0.0  0.0  26388  1896 ?        Ss   Apr25   0:03 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
dbus       856  0.0  0.0  66440  1868 ?        Ssl  Apr25   0:04 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root     58819  0.0  0.0 107968  1672 pts/0    S+   12:26   0:00 head
```

I also checked `tmpfs` filesystems and `/dev/shm`. None of these have any huge files.

What could be consuming all the memory? Any pointers on how to debug this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

Adding `cat proc/meminfo` output

```
MemTotal:       32605760 kB
MemFree:          405320 kB
MemAvailable:     185992 kB
Buffers:            8824 kB
Cached:            35724 kB
SwapCached:         5040 kB
Active:            23176 kB
Inactive:          31500 kB
Active(anon):       4064 kB
Inactive(anon):     6136 kB
Active(file):      19112 kB
Inactive(file):    25364 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      392167420 kB
SwapFree:       392123388 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          8684 kB
Mapped:            24512 kB
Shmem:                32 kB
Slab:             234744 kB
SReclaimable:      59568 kB
SUnreclaim:       175176 kB
KernelStack:        4224 kB
PageTables:         4932 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    408470300 kB
Committed_AS:     238592 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     8891936 kB
DirectMap2M:    24334336 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

Adding output of `df -t tmpfs`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           16302880     0  16302880   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           16302880  1340  16301540   1% /run
tmpfs           16302880     0  16302880   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          398458880 46050 398412830   1% /tmp
tmpfs            3260576     0   3260576   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs            3260576     0   3260576   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs            3260576     0   3260576   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Linux reporting "free" memory strangely?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449296/why-is-linux-reporting-free-memory-strangely)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please note that buff/cache is small. This is not a linuxatemyram.com thing.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Is this a VM?

Comment: Not a VM. A server in our data center.

Comment: Can you please edit the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` into your question?

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, can you add the output of `df -t tmpfs`?

Comment: No issues sir, added the output. :)

Comment: Can you add also `ipcs` command output?

Comment: Sorry, rebooted the system. I'll update here if I observe the issue again.